# How to merge two descending singly linkedlist into one ascending linkedlist using Recursion without any helper method?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, recursion, mergesort

[image]

**Here is my solution:
I want to know if my solution fits the requirement 100%? Or if there is any better solution?**

**Constraint of the question:**

1. must be singly linkedlist
2. must use recursion, and no helper methods allowed.
3. The method must return the head node of the merged list.

```
class Solution{
    Node dummy=new Node(0,null);// the dummy node to store the merged result

    public   Node mergeAscend(Node a,Node b){
        if(a==null&&b==null){//base case
            return null;
        }
               
        else{
            if((a!=null&&b==null)||a.value>=b.value){// insert "b" after dummy
                //store the next node of current a, before pointing a.next to dummy.next;
                Node store_a_next_node=a.next;
                //insert Node "a" between dummy and dummy.next
                a.next=dummy.next;
                dummy.next=a;
                mergeAscend(store_a_next_node,b);
            }
            else if((a==null&&b!=null)||a.value<b.value){//insert "a" after dummy
                Node store_b_next_node=b.next;
                b.next=dummy.next;
                dummy.next=b;
                mergeAscend(a,store_b_next_node);
            }
        }
        return  dummy.next;
    }
}
```

```
class Node {
    public int value;
    public Node next;

    public Node(int value, Node next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, for information, the `Node` class is missing, it's a bit hard to do a proper code review when the code is not compiling.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. I just added Node class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Compilation Error

The first problem is to solve the compiling error.

Just follow the interface:

```
    public Node<Integer> mergeAscend(Node<Integer> a, Node<Integer> b)
```

### Warnings and Code convention

You should add the type information to the store_next_a_node variable (and store_next_b_node). Additionally, in [Java naming conversion](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html), variable names use camel case. Therefore, I suggest substitute:

```
            Node store_next_a_node = a.next;
           ...
            Node store_next_b_node = b.next;
```

By...

```
            Node<Integer> nextNode = a.next;
```

#### Simple "Test Case"

The code bellow is just an example and not a full automated test (for more information, look for Java automated tests. eg: [junit tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html)).But it is enough to  give us some hints what is going on. For example, we can see the original code does not solve the problem. Let us write a simple test case:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        int[] a = { 6, 4, 2 };
        Node<Integer> h1 = new Node<>(8, null);
        Node<Integer> previous = h1;
        for (int value : a) {
            Node<Integer> node = new Node<>(value, null);
            previous.next = node;
            previous = node;
        }


        int[] b = { 7, 5, 3, 1 };
        Node<Integer> h2 = new Node<>(9, null);
        previous = h2;
        for (int value : b) {
            Node<Integer> node = new Node<>(value, null);
            previous.next = node;
            previous = node;
        }
        solution.mergeAscend(h1, h2);
        Node<Integer> iterator = solution.dummy;
        while (iterator != null) {
            System.out.println(iterator.value);
            iterator = iterator.next;
        }
    }
```

The expected output would be the numbers printed in ascending order as the exercise suggests.

### NullPointerException

With the test case, we can execute the code and and we will get a null pointer exception during the execution:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Solution.mergeAscend(Solution.java:13)
    at Solution.mergeAscend(Solution.java:19)
    at Solution.mergeAscend(Solution.java:24)
    at Solution.mergeAscend(Solution.java:19)
    at Solution.mergeAscend(Solution.java:24)
    at Solution.mergeAscend(Solution.java:19)
    at Solution.mergeAscend(Solution.java:24)
    at Solution.mergeAscend(Solution.java:19)
    at Solution.mergeAscend(Solution.java:24)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:50)
```

#### Bug

If you look the code, the following statement is suspicious:

```java
if((a!=null&&b==null)||a.value>=b.value)
```

What if `a` is null and b is not null? First condition is false and Java interpreter will try to evaluate the second condition. Unfortunately, a.value will throw a NullPointerException.

*Next Step: How to fix it ?*

### Clean Code makes our life easier

Let's make the code cleaner . In our case, we want to preserve the original code ideas and just simplifying what is possible. Hopefully we will remove the conditions that make the code to fail.

#### Remove unnecessary else-statement

First, after the base case, we don't need a else-statement. Change..

```java
        if (a == null && b == null) {//base case
            return null;
        }
        else {
        ...
        }
```

to

```java
        if (a == null && b == null) {//base case
            return null;
        }
        ...
```

#### Nullability test only once

Second, remove the complication of testing `a` nullability all the time.

Just add the following check after the base case.

```java
        if (a == null)
            return mergeAscend(b, a);
```

With that, now we know that `a` is the longest list and we don't need to check again and again that condition.

So, your second "if-statement" can be change from

```java
        if ( (a!=null && b==null) || a.value >= b.value)
```

to:

```java
        if (b == null || a.value >= b.value) // insert "b" after dummy
```

#### Remove unnecessary if-statement

After that, we might think about it... we don't need the third "if-statement". Just remove it.

```java
 else if((a==null&&b!=null)||a.value<b.value){
     ...
 }
```

To...

```java
 else {
      ...
  }
```

#### Congrats, your code now works!

```java
    public Node<Integer> mergeAscend(Node<Integer> a, Node<Integer> b) {
        if (a == null && b == null) {//base case
            return null;
        }
        if (a == null)
            return mergeAscend(b, a);
        if (b == null || a.value >= b.value) {// insert "a" after dummy
            //store the next node of current a, before pointing a.next to dummy.next;
            Node<Integer> nextNode = a.next;
            //insert Node "a" between dummy and dummy.next
            a.next = dummy.next;
            dummy.next = a;
            mergeAscend(nextNode, b);
        } else {
            Node<Integer> nextNode = b.next;
            b.next = dummy.next;
            dummy.next = b;
            mergeAscend(a, nextNode);
        }
        return dummy.next;
    }
```

Test it!

#### PS: Another Minor Thing - Comment misleading

Your code comments are misleading. In the second if-statement, if the statement evaluate the expression as true, code below add `a` between dummy and dummy.next.

change

```java
// insert "b" after dummy
```

To

```java
// insert "a" after dummy
```

### PS2: Symmetric symplification

Evaluating the code again, we might found the code is a little redundant. It means, part of the code is doing exactly the same thing, but the variable names are just swapped. In that case, we can simplify it further.

```java
    public Node<Integer> mergeAscend(Node<Integer> a, Node<Integer> b) {
        if (a == null && b == null) {//base case
            return dummy.next;
        }
        if (a == null || (b != null && a.value < b.value)) { // symmetric case
            return mergeAscend(b, a);
        }
        //store the next node of current a, before pointing a.next to dummy.next;
        //insert Node "a" between dummy and dummy.next
        Node<Integer> nextNode = a.next;
        a.next = dummy.next;
        dummy.next = a;
        return mergeAscend(nextNode, b);
    }
```

Comment: Wow,Thank you soooo much for this super detailed explanation! I have learned a lot.